# Android google maps API v2 route like in google maps app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am making an android app, and I want to show a route to the user, but if I create it via

```
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions(...));
```

it looks terrible. Just a solid line. How do Google draws its gradient route line with borders?

Is it possible for other developers to draw this route line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `TileOverlay`, but it would be a bit more work to generate. Draw portions of the route into `Bitmap`s and convert them to `byte[]` pngs or jpegs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library

it's realy easy to use

```
GoogleMap map = getMap();
Navigator nav = new Navigator(map,start,end);
nav.findDirections(true, false);
```

https://github.com/tyczj/MapNavigator

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "draws its gradient route line with borders" ?

Basically, if you have a list of points, you can draw the line like:

```
for (LatLng latLng : pointsArrayList) {
    polylineOptions.add(latLng);
}
mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

If the route data is accurate, the line you drawed will be fine.

If you mean the dotted line showd on Google Map, then you need to split your route data into several segment. Just like what google does:
[Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON)
(Please refer to the "legs" of json data)

Comment: I think I may get you wrong. You wanna customize the UI of the line you draw, right? If so, I'm looking forward the solution as well.

Comment: If I'll find it, I will answer my question. I have to find it.